# In my console game with C, '90' is printed instead of '9'

Tags: c, windows, console

I was making a console game with C on Visual Studio 2019. I made a code that print a variable.

It works only when value is greater than 10 .

If value of variable is less than 10 it **prints 10 instead of 1, 2 instead of 20 ... 9 instead of 90**.

I have no idea how to solve this problem.

Here is my code

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<windows.h>

int a =20;

void gotoxy(int x, int y) { //cursor goes to x, y
    COORD CursorPosition = { x,y };
    SetConsoleCursorPosition(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), CursorPosition);
}

void HideCursor() {
    HANDLE consoleHandle = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
    CONSOLE_CURSOR_INFO info;
    info.dwSize = 100;
    info.bVisible = FALSE;
    SetConsoleCursorInfo(consoleHandle, &info);
}

void count() {
    char c = _getch();
    switch (c) {
    case 'p': a++; break;
    case 'o': a--; break;
    }
}

int main() {
    system("mode con cols=10 lines=10");
    system("cls");
    HideCursor();
    while (1) {
        gotoxy(5, 5);
        count();
        printf("%d", a);
    }
}
```

Comment: *...2 instead of 20 ... 9 instead of 90....* I assume you mean *...20 instead of 2...90 instead of 9...*.

Comment: BTW: you forgot `#include <conio.h>`, didn't you get any compiler warnings?

Comment: Also, you might wanna call FlushConsoleInputBuffer after the "_getch", depending on what exactly "_getch()" does.

Comment: @Jabberwocky The OP is implementing a conio.h-like API rather than using pre-made functions.

Comment: @Lundin yes, but `_getch` (it's a standard Windows console thing) which is used by the OP's code is declared in `<conio.h>`. Actually he is implementing `gotoxy` which, I think, is a very old TurboC++ DOS thing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's because you don't overwrite the second digit if `a` becomes a single-digit number. You need to overwrite all previously written digits, for example by setting a field width:

```
// Print right-justified numbers, with empty spaces for one or two digit numbers
printf("%3d", a);
```